# How to create objects for default "Object" class in java ? As you know by default every class extends the object class

Tags: java

Since "Object" class is the parent of all classes, can we create objects for "Object" class?

Comment: Have you just tried it? What are your efforts so far?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
Object o = new Object();
```

`Object`s are hardly ever initialized as above, except when using them as low-level locks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

```
Object o = new Object();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A extends Objects{

Object object = new Object();

}
```

when you create object of object class ,object class constructor gets executed in the same way the class constructor executes.